# I am calling background after each 1 minute but it get called sometime 2 times in minute and sometime it does not get called android

Tags: android

```
public class SmartLoca extends Application {
  int repeatInterval = 60000; // 10 sec

  Timer repeatTask = new Timer();
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleService.class));
        }
    }, 0, repeatInterval);
  }
}
```

This is background service which I am calling after 1 minute, but it get called sometimes 2 times in minute and sometimes not get called in 3 to 4 minute as well.

Comment: repeat interval is 60 seconds i think

Comment: Yes but it get called 2 time within 60 seconds and sometime it never get called for 3 minutes as well,Can any one help me?

Comment: public class GoogleService extends Service implements LocationListener{

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the service, not in this timer. I would go step by step: comment out calling service and instead log the time in TimerTask. It it works OK, play with the service code to see what causes the trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but I am still unable to find exact reason.